# Convert JSON with Lists and dics into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a JSON file into dataframe that is easy to search and location useful information.
The JSON looks like following:

```
[
    {
        "testId": "test1",
        "testType": [
            {
                "value": "a",
                "startDate": "2019-01-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "candidate": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "id": "b",
                    "name": "test"
                },
                "startDate": "2019-01-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "testsite": [
            {
                "value": "c",
                "startDate": "2019-01-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "testId": "test2",
        "testType": [
            {
                "value": "SG",
                "startDate": "2019-01-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "maxcandidates": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "amount": "75"
                },
                "startDate": "2019-01-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "candidate": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "id": "sei",
                    "name": "long island Limited"
                },
                "startDate": "2019-01-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "mincandidates": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "amount": "5"
                },
                "startDate": "2018-04-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "testSite": [
            {
                "value": "5227",
                "startDate": "2018-04-01T08:00:00",
                "endDate": "2029-01-01T08:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It is part of the json file.
This JSON file contains lists and some of the attributes contains dictionary.
1 What is the most efficient way to normalize this data?
2 If I want to convert 'testType' into data frame with meta data of 'testId' across entire JSON file, how can I do it?

I use this command as

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('test.json') as f:
    d=json.load(f)

type=json_normalize(data=d[:]['testType'], 
                            meta=['testId'])
```

and it came out with TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

or if I use

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('test.json') as f:
    d=json.load(f)

type=json_normalize(data=d[0]['testType'], 
                            meta=['testId'])
```

I can convert it to data frame, but it can only give me first element in the array instead of everything.

Comment: What's your expected output? Can you show it?

Comment: Thank you.My expected output is the  aggregate of json_normalize(data=d[0]['testType'], meta=['testId']) but with all rows.

Comment: Basically, I would like to achieve the code goes into the json file, fetches all 'testType', convets them to dataframe and appends 'testId'

Comment: @Allen Hello Allen, how can I get all instead of first record? The cost only works with first record. d[0]                                   
But,  type=json_normalize(data=d[:]['testType'], 
                            meta=['testId']) fails.

Comment: Ok, just posted an answer. Please let me know if it's what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like:

```
pd.concat([json_normalize(data=e['testType'], meta=['testId']) for e in d])

value   startDate           endDate
0   a   2019-01-01T08:00:00 2029-01-01T08:00:00
0   SG  2019-01-01T08:00:00 2029-01-01T08:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you Allen. Does size of JSON file matter? I save the above json object into 'test.json' and run the code, with open('test.json') as f:
    d=json.load(f)
json_normalize(data=d[:],record_path='testType',meta=['testId'])    there is no error message.   But when I run the same code against my original json (have more than 100 records) then it fails with error: KeyError: 'testType'

Comment: When I ran testype=json_normalize(data=test[0:20], record_path='testType', 
                            meta=['testId'])  it is ok. But when I increase it to 50 When I ran testype=json_normalize(data=test[0:50], record_path='testType', 
                            meta=['testId']) , same error appears.